# NerdDinnerEntities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

what is NerdDinnerEntities in NerdDinner project, is it a class library or class? if it is class then where the dinner and Rsvp class should be? please don't say read the professional asap.net mvc2 book. i am getting this doubt only after reading that book.

Answer (score 1):

I think that NerdDinnerEntities is an EF4 Context. This let you perform data access operations in the Database. Take a look to any EF4 introductory tutorial. You will understand the basis in 20min.

I recomend you this one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/19/absolue-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework.aspx